# Настройка отображения элементов в RecyclerView через GridLayoutManager в строке

Tags: android

Необходимо настроить recyclerView таким образом, чтобы расположение элементов  в каждой второй строке было по 2, а в нечётных строках по одному item'у.

Как сделать по два элемента во всех строках, т.е. 2 колонки, - это понятно:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

а вот как сделать чередование - в одной два, а в другой один item?
Я подозреваю, что это какой-то метод `GridLayoutManager`'a, но как и где его применять? В `onCreateViewHolder`'е?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup( new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if((position % 3) == 0){
                    return 2;
                } else
                    return 1;
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Ярослав, пишите по-русски, вы на сайте StackOverflow на Русском.